# How to obtain Max(Rank) for a Specific Month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that looks like this

```
FORECAST_PERIOD  MONTH       COUNTRY    ENTRY_VIEW  V_TYPE  RES_CAT   MATCH_MONTH  RANK  VIS
June 2014 Week 1 01-JUL-2014  UK         Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   1    10
June 2014 Week 1 01-JUL-2014  USA        Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   1    5
June 2014 Week 1 01-JUL-2014  POLAND     Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   1    30
July 2014 Week 2 01-JUL-2014  UK         Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   2    15
July 2014 Week 2 01-JUL-2014  USA        Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   2    10
July 2014 Week 2 01-JUL-2014  UPOLAND    Forecast    SSV     110      01-JUL-2014   2    40
```

We have built in a Rank column in our view but perhaps unnecessarily.  Either way, we are trying to have a query return the max(rank) for each distinct month.  We do not want to aggregate the data, like sum, etc..we want to keep it at this level of granularity, but instead only pull back the rows in the view with the highest rank for each distinct month.  In the case above all of the rows with RANK 2 would be returned.  We are using the latest Oracle SQL.

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: `WHERE RANK = (SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM YourTable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use the `rank()` function:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*, rank() over (partition by month order by [rank] desc) as rankrank
      from view v
     ) v
where rankrank = 1;
```

Using this method, you probably don't need the `rank` column.  You can use whatever column is being ranked.

Comment: + there are two versions of rank in Oracle - RANK (may return not consequtive numbers) and DENSE_RANK (returns consequtive numbers)